# Which hook to use when adding ajax to viewer-facing side?

Tags: jquery, hooks, ajax, actions

I have a shortcode that contains a form. I want to use jQuery/Ajax for POSTing. For this, I want to add javascript to the page where shortcode is added? Which hook should I use?

1. wp_enqueue_scripts
2. wp_print_scripts
3. wp_print_footer_scripts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `wp_enqueue_scripts`, but you'll probably first want to:

1. Loop through the Posts
2. Grep your shortcode
3. Enqueue the script, if shortcode is found
4. Rewind Posts

That way, you only enqueue the script where necessary.

Comment: bennett Thanks! Would you please also tell what other two hooks do and what is the benefit of using `wp_enqueue_scripts` over them.